# How can I copy or move images from thousands of folders into one folder?

Tags: command-line, files

I have about 2855 folders containing a large number of images and I want to copy or move all the images into one folder.

Please provide a detailed explanation.

Comment: Can you give an idea of the naming scheme (if any) of the images? Are there other files in these directories that you do not want to move, or do you just want to move ALL the files from your 2855 folders into one? If you only want to move images, can they be identified by name (for example, do they end with `.png`)? To prevent files being overwritten when doing this, you should be confident that they all have unique names. It's safest to specify a new naming scheme. Can you provide any further info in an [edit] to your question, preferably with a sample of the directory structure with files

Comment: Be aware that nautilus will choke if you try to open a folder with such large amounts of files in a single folder.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Very Bad Idea.

However, assuming that your image names are unique (although duplicates will be handled by using `mv --backups-numbered`), and all your image-containing directories are under a directory called `$HOME/source`, and contain ONLY images (no files that should not be moved), and the the filenames *might* contain silly characters, and that the destination is `$HOME/destination`, then...

First read `man find`, `man xargs` and `man mv`. Then a simple

```
find $HOME/source -type f -print0 |\
    xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty mv --target-directory=$HOME/destination/ --backup=numbered
```

Reread `man find`, `man xargs` and `man mv` for detailed explanation.

After this finishes, you'll be left with a whole lot of empty directories under `$HOME/source`, which can be removed with

```
find $HOME/source -depth -type d -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty rmdir
```

Read `man rmdir`.

Comment: The removal of the directories can also be written as `find $HOME/source -type d -delete`.

Comment: @PerlDuck `-delete` will delete non-empty directories! `rmdir` will only delete empty directories.

Comment: True. But if I understood your first `find` command correctly, the directories _are_ empty when it has run.

Comment: Honestly, I would create hardlinks instead of moving the files as a first approach and then see how such a crowded target directory behaves. [Jacob](https://askubuntu.com/users/72216/jacob-vlijm) said in a comment that _"nautilus will choke"_. With hardlinks this can easily be undone. The command would be `find $HOME/source -type f -exec ln --target-directory=$HOME/destination --backup=numbered {} +`. No `xargs` or quoting is required because `find` calls `ln` with `{}` properly replaced by each filename and the `+` instead of `\;` calls it with as many args as fit into the commandline.

Comment: It overwrites the files with same names. Tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Change directory `cd` to the directory where all the folders are.
This will move all files in your working folder and subfolders to one folder. Different files with same name will remain in the original folders

**Run the commands with caution. Running from a wrong location may cause loss of important files.**

Run:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I _ mv -vn _ /path/to/copy/
```

if you want files with some ext e.g. .jpg

Run:

```
find . \( -name '*.jpg' -or -name '*.png' \) -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I _ mv -vn _ /path/to/copy/
```

Comment: Why `sort`? Why a shell loop, rather than `xargs`?

Comment: Thanks [waltinator](https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator).

Comment: Why `xargs -I _`? You could use `mv`'s `--target-directory=DIRECTORY` switch, e.g.: `xargs -0 mv --target-directory=/path/to/copy`